# Warning from Cloudflare: Math.SE/mathoverflow acting weird

Tags: bug, se-sites

I was treated with

> This page (https://mathoverflow.net/) is currently offline. However, because the site uses CloudFlare's Always Online™ technology you can continue to surf a snapshot of the site. We will keep checking in the background and, as soon as the site comes back, you will automatically be served the live version. Always Online™ is powered by CloudFlare | Hide this Alert

when I tried visiting the mathoverflow yesterday. I ignored it since I was able to access the site after couple of reloads.

But today morning, math.SE is acting weird (sometimes it takes couple of reloads to load, sometimes it loads at blazing speed) and was treated with a full page error few seconds back from Cloudfare saying math.SE is down.

Adding: Cloudflare showed some additional info that it could connect to Cloudflare servers in Chennai, and not the main server.

What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like CloudFlare's own issues: they had a problem specifically in India yesterday, as reported on https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/

> CloudFlare: "we may not be able to find your site, but we'll guarantee your customers will see an error page implying it's your fault" -- [Shog9](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3641162#3641162)

Regional connectivity issues were also acknowledged on Twitter by [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus).

Hopefully, all this is transient.

Comment: Error 522, Ray ID: 26a232c5c3932ff9 • 2016-01-25 07:17:41 UTC out of nowhere again!

Comment: It's still happening: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/693080717920567296

Comment: @Minerstrone, SE is not alone, been receiving the same with many other sites using cloudflare (though I haven't received the error here in math.SE last two days!)